# Word VBA save files in new folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have VBA in Word that opens multiple files from a folder that I select, replaces the logo in the header with a new file that I direct it to, and then saves the files in a different folder.

I have the files saving in a different folder not because I want to, but because they are opening as read-only and I can't figure out how to make that not happen. I have tried everything I can find on here. I'm fine with them saving to a new folder. That's not the issue for me right now.

Right now, this code works, but I have to click "Save" for each document. I would like that to be automated. The code right here is the saveas

```
End With
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
.Name = "\\i-worx-san-07.i-worx.ca\wardell$\Redirection\billy.bones\Desktop\Test 3\" & ActiveDocument.Name
.Show
End With

End With
objDocument.SaveAs
objDocument.Close (True)
```

The following is the complete VBA code. I'm an absolute novice, so go easy. I want to know how to go about making the saveas include the original filename, a new specified folder (can be specified in the code, doesn't have to be specified by the user) and do it without the user having to press "save" a brazillion times. I appreciate your help.

```
Sub Example1()
'Declaring the required variables
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim arrFiles() As String
Dim i As Integer
'the dialog is displayed to the user
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
'dispaly message box
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
    'Get all the files paths and store it in an array
arrFiles() = GetAllFilePaths(strPath)
'Modifying all the files in the array path
For i = LBound(arrFiles) To UBound(arrFiles)
    Call ModifyFile(arrFiles(i))
Next i
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ModifyFile(ByVal strPath As String)
Dim objDocument As Document
Set objDocument = Documents.Open(strPath)
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
.Headers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
End With
    Dim imagePath As String
    'Please enter the relative path of the image here
    imagePath = "C://FILEPATH\FILENAME.jpg"
   Set oLogo = .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    With oLogo.Range
       .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
       'Right alignment for logo image
       .ParagraphFormat.RightIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.6)
    End With
End With
With oLogo
    .Height = 320
    .Width = 277

With Selection.PageSetup
    'Header from Top value
    .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
End With
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
.Name = "\\i-worx-san-07.i-worx.ca\wardell$\Redirection\billy.bones\Desktop\Test 3\" & ActiveDocument.Name
.Show
End With

End With
objDocument.SaveAs
objDocument.Close (True)
End Sub
Private Function GetAllFilePaths(ByVal strPath As String) _
As String()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrOutput() As String
ReDim arrOutput(1 To 1)
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and
'prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
ReDim Preserve arrOutput(1 To i)
'print file path
arrOutput(i) = objFile.Path
i = i + 1
Next objFile
GetAllFilePaths = arrOutput
End Function
```

Comment: I am surprised this `imagePath = "C://FILEPATH\FILENAME.jpg"` worked for you. You can preset the folders like `Const FDR1 = "\\Server\Folder"` on top of all Sub. You also have an inefficient way to get the list of files in a folder. Do you omit files in it's subfolders?

Comment: Solved by L42 Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line which calls the `FileSaveAs` dialogue.

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = "\\i-worx-san-07.i-worx.ca\wardell$\Redirection\billy.bones\Desktop\Test 3\" & ActiveDocument.Name
    .Show
End With
```

Then modify this line:

```
objDocument.SaveAs
```

and include the filepath like this:

```
objDocument.SaveAs "\\i-worx-san-07.i-worx.ca\wardell$\Redirection\" _
    & "billy.bones\Desktop\Test 3\" & ActiveDocument.Name
```

In newer version of Word, it was change to [`SaveAs2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx) but `SaveAs` still works.
That method takes the file path where you want the file saved as first argument.